# Alternating authorization in Apache JMeter

Tags: authentication, jmeter, authorization

When using BASIC_DIGEST as authorization in Apache JMeter, is it possible to setup authorization for each independent thread group?

Using the HTTP Authorization Manager

Lets say for two thread groups :

```
User Type A : Username usr1, Password 123
User Type B : Username usr2, Password 321
```

Anyone knows or can provide a link?

Comment: @user7294900, i am using BASIC_DIGEST Authorization for the whole test plan. I just found that you can simply add the authorization to each independent thread group instead and that solved it.
I am closing the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Authorization Manager follows [Scoping Rules](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/ScopingRules) so you can basically add a HTTP Authorization Manager as a child of the individual HTTP Request sampler and it will be applied to this sampler only.

Also you can parameterise it using [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) if needed.

---

Alternatively you can add a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send `Authorization` header with the value of:

```
Basic ${__base64Encode(usr1:123,)}
```

You will need [__base64Encode() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) installed in order to make this approach work.

See [Basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) article for more details.

Comment: Accepting this detailed answer.
Thanks for the info!